# Can't reinstall grub from Live CD after reinstalling Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

How do I reinstall grub, after I have reinstalled Windows XP on dual boot system?

I have Ubuntu 14.10 installed, and I'm trying to reinstall grub from Ubuntu 10.04 Live CD. However, I cannot install [boot-repair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows/182863#182863) (`E: Couldn't find package boot-repair`) and I have no idea what "main partition" refers to [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows/182863#182863). Is it the partition I have Ubuntu 14.10 installed on (`/dev/sda2`) or the one with Windows (`/dev/sda1`)?

**Solution:** The problem was that I was using Ubuntu 10.04 Live CD. `boot-repair` installed right away from Ubuntu 14.10 Live USB and it solved the problem.

Comment: Let us focus on getting boot repair to work. Specifically what happens when you try to install it?  Can you use a newer distro with a Live CD?

Comment: Well, I add the repository, but when I try to install boot-repair, I get the "E: Couldn't find package boot-repair" error. I've downloaded the Boot Repair Live CD and dd'ed it to a USB, but the USB then doesn't boot up. I'll try installing boot-repair within a newer distro.

Comment: Cool! I thought it might be the old distro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'main partition' referred in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/367990) is the partition on which your Ubuntu is installed. It is the one you mount as file system root (`/` directory) when you boot Ubuntu normally. So yes, in your case it would be /dev/sda2.

Your other option was to use boot repair instead of manually reinstalling GRUB. Probably you forgot to install the PPA (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`) or to update your software index list afterwards (`sudo apt-get update`). Note that you need a working internet connection for this. Otherwise you would have to download it as `.deb`-file and install it manually with `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/file.deb`.

But anyway, you should use a newer version of Ubuntu as live system. 10.04 is now 5 years old and hits end-of-life in April 2015. Better use 14.04 LTS (from April 2014, 5 years support) or 14.10 (from October 2014, 9 months support). The next release will be 15.04 (in April 2015, 9 months support).

Comment: I did add the repository and I did update the index list, but now I see that when I do update it, the yannubuntu rep is being ignored (`Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/ lucid/main Translation-en_US`). Also, I have 14.10 installed (not 14.04 as I said), but the 10.04 is the latest live Ubuntu CD I have and I didn't want to go through the hassle of creating a fresher Live USB.

Comment: That is not true - the PPA is not ignored, only the en_US translations. Run `sudo apt-get update | grep boot-repair` and you will see at least one line with "OK" or "Hit" which means that the index is up to date. (Or "Get" if it is fetching a new version).

Comment: This is the only line I get with grep: `Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/ lucid/main Translation-en_US`.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem from Ubuntu 14.10 Live USB. `boot-repair` installed right away from 14.10.

Comment: Cool. So it seems like it was just that 10.04 is not compatible with the recent boot-repair version. Good to know for further answers. Leave me a comment if you still have problems after trying boot-repair.